# Questions about Android listview

Tags: android-listview

If I have more than 100 items in listview then is there any better solution than creating new 100 classes and XML files for staring new activity on click of each list item?

Using switch case and array of list items I can  create but I am searching better solution than this

I am new to Android development

If any one having any idea please share it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What it sounds like is you need ONE view that is built with dynamic content.  So, based on what is chosen from the dropdown, you set a group of variables, and then launch the view, passing them in.

Comment: You should select only the items you need to show from time to time (filtering the query through a WHERE clause).

Comment: So I hv to create database instead of array of list item I m not getting properly can u share some example

Comment: I am having predefined list of items in my project but it is having around 150 items in list and after clicking on item there must be new page which shows some  text and images on next page

Comment: Use Google: `android listview master detail database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:
*"I am having predefined list of items in my project but it is having around 150 items in list and after clicking on item there must be new page which shows some text and images on next page"*

So make only **one new Activity** and display text and images **depending on the selected item**. At the **onCreate-Method** of your Activity ask for the selected value from the list (you can transport this item/its name as a String with a **Bundle**). And depending on the selected item you generate your text and your images and - if needed - their functionality.